# About difference of selector's interpretation when launching or not developer tool with Edge

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors, microsoft-edge

**What I want to know**

Whether there is a difference in interpretation between selector and DOM on / off of developer tool.
If you have good books, good literature (web-page) about other mechanisms and behaviors of the browser, please post me.

**Issue**

At Edge, it only works as expected when launching the developer tool,
then, closing the developer tool did not work as expected.

**Confirmed**

I found two cases below and confirmed.

- Case where console.log () remained.
- Case where the cache was left.

No matter what solution I tried, my problem was not solved.

I thought that it was peculiar to Edge, I confirmed the Web page of Microsoft's developer tools for just in case,
I can not obtain particularly powerful information.

**Final modification**

Below is the code of .js.

There was a deficiency in the selector I used for jquery, so I corrected it and confirmed the expected behavior.

The direct cause was forgotten in parentheses.

- $ ("input [value = hoge"). parent (). show ();
- $ ("input [value = hoge]"). parent (). show ();
   History of correction

Since it is specific only when the developer tool is off in the first place,
Basically I chased with alert ().

Thanks.